# Moving packages eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Maybe a stupid question but I have two packages in eclipse and now I would like to move the one package into the other for better structure.

Now I tried move but that generates a copy into the same package.

And with refactoring -> move I even can't select the packages

Can anyone help me....

thx all

Comment: I consider this a bug. When you drag and drop a node from one location to another, within the same tree, the accepted expected behaviour is a move-rename. The behaviour in eclipse package explorer is highly unusual and confusing. Either that eclipse team have been unable to achieve the skills to implement drag-drop move-rename, or have been obstinately enforcing unusual behaviour to establish a "norm" that is distinctly eclipse.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you have `com.company.foo` and `com.company.bar`, and want to move `foo` into `bar`, then just rename `com.company.foo` to `com.company.bar.foo`.

If you package happens to have subpackages, tick `Rename subpackages` to move the subpackages as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't move sub-packages in foo. So if you have foo.a and move foo to bar, foo.a still remains where it was.

Comment: Worked a bit with it and I get something I can live with ... did some refactoring and it's still working so I'm fine with it.

Comment: I don't have any sub-packages so I can live with this as a solution.  But I still wondr if there is a full answer.

Comment: For the subpackages you have to check the box `Rename subpackages` in the refactoring dialog.

Answer (score 23):

Use the package explorer view and rename the package. It asks for renaming updating references, renaming sub packages, update textual references in comments and and also non-Java text files. Click on the preview and then ok.

Comment: I would add that it is best to use `ctrl+shift+r` to refactor the pacakage and not just press `F2` to rename as some might gather from your answer

Answer (score 16):

I have found the solution, when you rename a package to the desired destination, check on the box "rename subpackages" and there you go! :) – user1525788 Jul 10 at 9:14

Comment: you have to remember  - #1 ) rename instead of move and #2)rename subpackages  #3) no Drag n Drop :D

Comment: Works. This should be the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

if you have current package:

- com.insect.fly

and would like to add subpackage to it, then renaming will solve the purpose e.g.

- com.insect.fly.mosquitto

However, eclipse do not should it in nested style. Just do
Package Explorer > click on v button on the pane next to minimize > package presentation > Hierarchical

Hope that SOLVES  !!

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly non-intuitive, but the best way to do it is by right clicking on the package you wish to move, clicking on `refactor`, and then on `rename`.

Then proceed to enter the fully qualified path which you desire.

For example, if you wish that a package called `dog` be moved into a package called `mammals` which itself is in a package called `animals` you would essentially rename your `dog` package to `animals.mammals.dog`

In other words, the package structure

[image]

is represented as `animals.mammals.dog` in the world of Java packages, and a renaming achieves the desired effect.

Please note that you *must* not try to achieve this by manually moving the folders in Windows explorer. These actions are best done using your IDE.

Answer (score -1):

this is rlly old but try opening in hierarchy mode. `in project explorer click the small arrow (pointing down) > package presentation > hierarchical.`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and doesn't change the package copying behavior described by OP.

Comment: answer is not relative to question.